# Issues when passing timestamp in grpc

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

How do I pass a timestamp to my grpc client . I get the below error.
I passed the time stamp in single quotes and other wise as below but that did not work. When I don't pass as_of it works fine.

grpc_cli call trade-server:143 trade.model.Service/GetDeals "bucket_id: 1644239, source_system: PROGRA, as_of: 2019-01-02T00:00:00Z" >> /home/deals.txt

The request is of the below format

```
source_system SourceSystem 
bucket_id   int64 
as_of   Timestamp optional
```

**Error**
Failed to parse text format to proto.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the grpc object **google.protobuf.Timestamp** (the source code is [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto))

Example:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message UserInfo {
    int32 user_id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp last_login_time = 2;
}
```